# Regular Expression for schema and table name

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that covers this syntax:
[schema].[table]
I need to validate that the table name has and schema name and also brings the square brakes.

Comment: Do you have anything yet?

Comment: Would you please expand your question, providing a bit more information and relevant examples of what you want?

Comment: I need to do a dynamic query using a schema and table and I want to be sure the schema and table name comes in that format with brakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches your pattern:

```
^\[\w+\]\.\[\w+\]$
```

The `\w` term (letters, digits and underscore) happens to fit nicely with standard SQL names.

If you want to allow *any* characters in names (like space, hyphen, whatever) use this:

```
^\[[^\]]+\]\.\[[^\]]+\]$
```