# Removing data from string using regular expressions in C Sharp

Tags: regex

Definitely I'm not good using regular expressions but are really cool!, Now I want to be able to get only the name "table" in this string:

```
[schema].[table]
```

I want to remove the schema name, the square brackets and the dot.

so I will get only the work table

I tried this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(reader["Name"].ToString(), @"[\[\.\]]", "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you [came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882693/regular-expression-for-schema-and-table-name) with a new idea?? Here is what you can try:

```
string input = "[schema].[table]";

// replacing the first thing into [] with the dot with empty
string one = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\[.*?\]\.", "");

// or replacing anything before the dot with empty
// string two = Regex.Replace(input, @".*[.]", "");
```

Comment: Actually I could have data in two different format with this: [].[] or  only the table name. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I try to understand this pattern ".*[.]", this means I'm searching a dot character zero or more times right? and this part [.] what is representing?

Comment: You are right about the `.*`. And `[.]` means the character `dot`. `[]` is character class. You can place multiple characters there and regex will pick one of those. You can use [this link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) to get explanation of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string strRegex = @"^\[.*?\]\.";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"[schema].[table]";
string strReplace = @"";

var result=myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do replace if you just want to **extract** part of string?

```
string table = Regex.Match("[schema].[table]", @"\w+(?=]$)").Value;
```

It works even in case if you don't have schema.